# cant conennect to db from my node.js app using mysql packege

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

must your help!!!
it throw me

> Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 10.166.186.156:3306
>       at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1128:14)

here my code :

```
const express = require("express");
const mysql = require("mysql");

const app = express();

const db = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "DESKTOP-2QNN9FA",
  user: "DuduLog",
  password: "1234",
  database: "testDB"
});

db.connect(err => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  } else console.log("MySql Connected...");
});

app.listen("3000", () => {
  console.log("Server started on port 3000");
});
```

what worng with it? thanks a lot

Comment: Check your firewall, or more likely, your MYSQL server may not be bound to that ip address - they changed the default setting at some point to prevent people unwittingly setting up mysql servers that listened to all ip addresses

Comment: make sure that your server does allow requests to that port from outside. I guess on my Debian th server configs were blocking all ports except `80` and `8080` and maybe `422` by default

Comment: how can i change it?

Comment: does your express app really run on another system than your mysql server does? Please provide some information like which OS you are using, configured firewalls, reverse proxies and so on

Comment: Finally, I solved it ....the problam was the host name.....stupid me!

Answer (score 0):

try use component mysql-ssh.

```
const connect = mysqlssh.connect({
                host: 'xxxxxx',
                user: 'xxxxxxx',
                password: 'xxxxxx',
                port: xx
            },
            {
                host: '127.0.0.1',
                user: 'xxxxx',
                password: 'xxxxx',
                database: 'xxxxxx',
                port: 'xxxx'
            })
```

if you use firebase functions you need to configure the panel with a payment method that supports connections to other servers